# qt button to emit multiple signals

Tags: qt, signals, mouseevent

is there a Qt (I use Qt 4.7.1) widget that emit signals (not just one at the first time) while it is pressed and stops when the user releases the mouse?  something like mousedown events in standard intervals?
or do I have to implement this with a qtimer? 
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [QAbstractButton::autoRepeat](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeat-prop) and autoRepeatInterval. It should be exactly what you need and is available for all buttons.

Comment: +1 For discovering feature the OP wanted (and correctly answering the question :))

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement something that fire the event until the user release the mouse.

I suggest you to create an handler class connected to the button event that fires custom events as you like to its observers.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>As far as I know there is no such button widget.</strike>The `QPushButton`'s `autoRepeat` should do just what you want. But would not the [`QPushButton::pressed()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractbutton.html#pressed) and [`QPushButton::released()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractbutton.html#released) signals be enought for your needs?

Anyway, what you are describing would be quite easy (and redundant, since it already exists) to implement, connect the [`QTimer::timeout()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtimer.html) signal to the signal you want and then just start the timer on `pressed()` signal and stop it on `released()` signal :)

Edit: As pointed out in comments, there is an inbuild solution and that is setting property [`autoRepeat`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeat-prop) inherited from [`QAbstractButton`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeat-prop) to `true`.

You can customise the initial delay and interval by adjusting [`autoRepeatDelay`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeatDelay-prop) and [`autoRepeatInterval`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeatDelay-prop).

Comment: ok thanks this is what I had in mind as a solution. thanks for the confirmation that there is no qwidget with this functionality

Comment: But there is! See Frank Osterfeld's answer

Comment: Ah, did not know about that, sorry :)