# How to distinguish between pressed, released and long press when using QAbstractButton::autoRepeat

Tags: c++, linux, qt, button, qt4.8

I am using Qt 4.8.X on Linux with X11 and/or Qt-QWS with custom buttons derived from QAbstractButton. Now I have to distinguish between a button press, release and the user holding down the button. To do so, I would like to use QAbstractButton::autoRepeat as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896699/qt-button-to-emit-multiple-signals).
As the [QT Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeat-prop) states

> If autoRepeat is enabled, then the pressed(), released(), and clicked() signals are emitted at regular intervals.

Well, how can I now distinguish between actually pressing down, holding down and releasing the button when all three Signals get emitted together? Your ideas are very welcome. Thanks and greeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using autoRepeat is not the best idea here. I do not know what you want to do exactly, but my first guess would be leaving autoRepeat off. If the user presses the button, you get your pressed signal. In that callback you can start a timer that fires in your desired "auto Repeat" interval. If the user releases the button again (signal released), your just stop or kill the timer.

Comment: Thats exactly the solution I am currently using as a workaround. But when QAbstractButton provides that feature, why not use it? What puzzles me is how the original QT developers intended autoRepeat to be used...

Comment: autoRepeat does something like key-repeat in your operating system. if you press the backspace key for a long time, it will be triggered again and again. Windows doesn't care if the current trigger is the first one or the 2583st. it just fires "delete last character" every time. Same for QAbstractButton autoRepeat. I think your use-case does not match that very good.

Comment: that sounds like a reasonable explanation. Thanks jwsc!